# how can have an array of html input type="button" in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have 3 `Html input button` in my web page.

```
<input id="Meal0" runat="server" type="button" class="btn-free arrayinput" />

<input id="Meal1" runat="server" type="button" class="btn-busy arrayinput" />

<input id="Meal2" runat="server" type="button" class="btn-primary arrayinput" />
```

now I want to have an array of 3 elements in my jquery function:

```
      here is my all code:

  $("#btnNextWeek").click(function (e) {

    var MealsButton = $('.arrayinput');


                    var Meals = s.split('!~!');
                    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {

                        MealsButton[i].css("color", "black");
                        MealsButton[i].css("width", "200px");
                        MealsButton[i].css("height", "60px");

                        if (Attr[1] == "1") {
                            MealsButton[i].css("class", "btn-app btn-success btn arrayinput");
                            MealsButton[i].css("Buy", Attr[4] + ":" + Attr[3]);
                            MealsButton[i].val("خرید ژتون");
                        }

                        else if (Attr[2] == "1" && Attr[5] != "empty chip") {
                            MealsButton[i].css("class", "btn-app btn-free btn arrayinput");
                            MealsButton[i].css("DelBtn", Attr[5]);
                            if (Attr[6] != "empty chip") {
                                if (Attr[6] != "empty chip") {
                                      MealsButton[i].val(Attr[6]);

                                }

                                else {
                                      MealsButton[i].css("class", "btn-app btn-disable btn arrayinput");

                                    if (Attr[6] != "empty chip") {
                                           MealsButton[i].val(Attr[6]);

                                    }
                                    else {
                                        MealsButton[i].val("");


                                    }
                                }
                            }



                        }

                        }
      });
```

this error ocured :

```
 0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

how can i have an array of my html input elements and how can access to my array elements ??
thanks a lot.

Comment: Just run this on my console and worked...

var MealsButton = [$("body"), $("html"), $("p")];
console.log(MealsButton);

Comment: You have an extra `}` for the closing part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me make a suggestion.

Give a custom class to the inputs

```
           <input id="Meal0" runat="server" class="arrayinput" type="button" />
            <input id="Meal1" runat="server" class="arrayinput" type="button" />
            <input id="Meal2" runat="server" class="arrayinput" type="button" />
```

And Script can go like

```
  $("#btnNextWeek").click(function (e) {

var MealsButton = $('.arrayinput');

} });
```

Meals button will be the array of inputs as you want it.

You can use `MealsButton` variable to add any properties since it is equivalent to the selector.

For example

```
MealsButton.css('width','200px');
```

If you want to access each element separately. Then

```
MealsButton.each(function (index, value) {

           $(this).css('width','200px');

});
```

**Find Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Aneeshmohan/qef92ajf/6/)**

Comment: You can always add additional class without causing any side effects like class="btn-free arrayinput" "btn-busy arrayinput" etc @Farna

Comment: I Edit my question,now how can access to each element in MealsButton array?

Comment: You want to add the width as in question ?? @Farna

Comment: No,I want to add many properties,here width is an example only .

Comment: :how can work with this array?i want to access to each element.

Comment: Your problem is solved right. Try to implement your logic on your own rather using someone who wanted to help you. @Farna

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specifically wrong with what you are doing, however the resulting variable with give you an array containing three jQuery objects. From your question it sounds like you want one jQuery object which contains the three elements.

You could comma separate your selectors to get all three elements in one jQuery object:

```
$("#btnNextWeek").click(function (e) {
    var $mealsButton = $("#Meal0, #Meal1, #Meal2");
}
```

Alternatively you could add a class to the elements and select by that:

```
<input id="Meal0" runat="server" type="button" class="button" />
<input id="Meal1" runat="server" type="button" class="button" />
<input id="Meal2" runat="server" type="button" class="button" />
```

```js
$("#btnNextWeek").click(function (e) {
    var $mealsButton = $(".button");
}
```

Note that in both examples the elements contained in the `$mealButton` variable will be exactly the same.